# GetButtonDown for Unity keyboard UI navigation?

Tags: unity, input, gui

By default, Unity's keyboard navigation for buttons seems to check for GetButton rather than GetButtonDown--if a menu has 5 items and I hold the down arrow, it'll scroll very quickly to the bottom.

This feels awkward; it would make more sense to check for GetButtonDown and only move 1 space per input. However, I can't find any option to let me change that. Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there's currently no way to make Unity's keyboard navigation to use `GetButtonDown` instead of `GetButton`.

However, **EventSystem** -> **Standalone Input Module** exposes an **Input Actions per Second** variable.

The default value is *10 seconds*.
If you change it to a lower value, like *3*, you will slow down considerably the scroll to bottom speed.

Because picking a low value for this setting will limit your in-game input, you might want to set different values in your menu and game scenes via code.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.html

Comment: Hm, okay. But wouldn't that result in the game throwing out some inputs?

Comment: You are correct. For this reason, you might want to set different values for this setting (via code) in your menu and game scenes.

Comment: It might make more sense to use StandaloneInputModule.repeatDelay and set it to somewhere between 0.5f-1.0f that way the User can tap the arrow key to navigate menu items like normal but holding it down won't immediately start scrolling rapidly. Setting this to a really high value would simulate using GetButtonDown since it wouldn't repeat unless the key was held down for a long period.

Comment: `repeatDelay` sounds like it would work perfectly, but I can't seem to access it. My script is already `using UnityEngine.EventSystems`, but when I type in the class `StandaloneInputModule`, I don't get any of its variables.